# Apache2's Multiple SSL hosts configuration (with different keys)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tls

Well, this problem is relatively hard to describe. I installed Webmin+Virtualmin in a server. I have multiple IP addresses in the server (two NICs bonded).

Let's assume that the network is *1.1.1.1/29*.

The Virtual Servers now are like this:

*masterdomain.com*:

- Listens to all addresses (*1.1.1.2* to *1.1.1.6*)
- Self-signed certificate for SSL (issuer masterdomain.com)

*seconddomain.com*:

- Listens to *1.1.1.4*
- Self-signed certificate for SSL (issuer seconddomain.com)

You see, there's no problem at all using HTTPS at masterdomain.com (other than complains because the certificate isn't signed by a CA). TLSv1 says Server Hello, exchanges key, and it's done.

The problem comes with https://1.1.1.4/ or https://seconddomain.com/. Firefox says **ssl_error_rx_record_too_long**.

I used Wireshark to examine the packets, and found that it (*seconddomain.com* or *1.1.1.4*) never sends the key or the 'Hello', but the index.php of the DocumentRoot of seconddomain.com within the TLSv1 response. Wireshark classifies it as `Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unexpected Message)`. The first 66 bytes conform with the expected header, and then Apache inserts the processed index.php -> `"<html><head><title>Main page of seconddomain.com!![...]"` instead of the SSL key. That's in the packet were it is supposed to put the "Server Hello" (after a correct "Client Hello" from the client).

I don't know how to solve the issue, which is most likely related to the VirtualHost configuration. But the VirtualHost of seconddomain.com has the same configuration than masterdomain.com! -other than listening to only one IP instead of * (and of course, the SSL key, the SuexecGroup and the DocumentRoot fields are different).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste in the copy of your VirtualHost Configuration?

Comment: Hi Rilindo, thanks for your comment. I already solved the issue.

Comment: Great. Make sure to accept your post and close it.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days for accepting my own answer... but sure, I will close it. If you think it may not help others, feel free to delete it. Salud!

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. You see, Virtualmin generated this in `apache2.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.2:80
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.2:443
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.4
```

Therefore not distinguishing between the https and http ports of 1.1.1.4. Replaced it for:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.2:80
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.2:443
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.4:80
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.4:443
```

To solve the problem.